# How to put a border around every single element?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

right now I only have one big border, however I want to put borders around each elements I have on the header and I want to change the background inside those borders.  [image: Here's the picture of the website]

```css
.home #site-header {
  height: 100vh;
}

#site-header {
  position: relative;
  height: 50vh;
  background-image: url("assets/images/kluane.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

#site-header a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#site-identity-container {
  position: absolute;
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#site-identity {
  background-color: var(--color-bg);
  opacity: .45;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: var(--spacing-half);
  margin: auto;
  padding: var(--spacing);
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid var(--color-text);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  max-width: -webkit-calc(100% - -webkit-calc(var(--spacing) * 4));
  max-width: calc(100% - calc(var(--spacing) * 4));
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.site-title {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: var(--color-text);
}

.site-tagline {
  font-size: 18px;
}

/* 4.1 Site Header: Navigation */
#header-nav-toggle {
  display: none;
}

#header-nav-toggle-label {
  background-color: var(--color-bg-alt);
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 24px;
  height: 16px;
  padding: var(--spacing-half);
  top: var(--spacing-half);
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

#header-nav-toggle-label span,
#header-nav-toggle-label span::before,
#header-nav-toggle-label span::after {
  background-color: var(--color-text-alt);
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

#header-nav-toggle-label span {
  top: -1px;
  bottom: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - var(--spacing));
  width: calc(100% - var(--spacing));
}

#header-nav-toggle-label span::before, #header-nav-toggle-label span::after {
  content: '';
}

#header-nav-toggle-label span::before {
  top: -8px;
}

#header-nav-toggle-label span::after {
  bottom: -8px;
}

#header-nav-toggle:checked ~ #header-nav-toggle-label span {
  left: -30px;
}

#header-nav-toggle:checked ~ #header-nav-toggle-label span::before, #header-nav-toggle:checked ~ #header-nav-toggle-label span::after {
  left: -webkit-calc(30px + var(--spacing-half));
  left: calc(30px + var(--spacing-half));
}

#header-nav-toggle:checked ~ #header-nav-toggle-label span::before {
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
          transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#header-nav-toggle:checked ~ #header-nav-toggle-label span::after {
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
          transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

#header-nav-toggle:checked ~ #header-navs-container {
  display: grid;
}

#header-navs-container {
  display: none;
  background-color: var(--color-bg-alt);
  position: absolute;
  color: var(--color-text-alt);
  width: 100%;
  max-width: -webkit-calc(100% - var(--spacing-double));
  max-width: calc(100% - var(--spacing-double));
  padding: var(--spacing);
  top: -webkit-calc(24px + var(--spacing));
  top: calc(24px + var(--spacing));
  text-transform: uppercase;
  z-index: 1;
}

#header-nav,
#site-header .social-nav {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
      -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
}

#header-nav a,
#site-header .social-nav a {
  color: var(--color-text-alt);
}

#header-nav li,
#site-header .social-nav li {
  list-style: none;
}

#header-nav a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#header-nav li {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: var(--spacing-half);
}

#site-header .social-nav li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: var(--spacing);
}

#header-nav ~ .social-nav {
  border-top: 1px solid var(--color-text-alt);
  padding-top: var(--spacing-half);
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  #header-nav-toggle-label {
    display: none;
  }
  #header-navs-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    grid-gap: var(--spacing);
    width: auto;
    top: var(--spacing);
  }
  #header-nav > li,
  #site-header .social-nav > li {
    padding: 0;
  }
  #header-nav li {
    width: auto;
  }
  #header-nav > li {
    position: relative;
  }
  #header-nav > li:not(:first-child) {
    padding-left: var(--spacing-half);
  }
  #header-nav > li:not(:last-child) {
    padding-right: var(--spacing-half);
  }
  #header-nav > li > ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: var(--color-bg-alt);
    padding: var(--spacing);
    left: -webkit-calc(var(--spacing) * -1);
    left: calc(var(--spacing) * -1);
    min-width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 10;
  }
  #header-nav > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
  }
  #header-nav ~ .social-nav {
    border-top: none;
    padding: 0;
    border-left: 1px solid var(--color-text-alt);
    padding-left: var(--spacing);
  }
}
*/
/* 5.0 Content */
:root {
  font-size: var(--font-size);
}

body {
  background-color: var(--color-bg);
  color: var(--color-text);
  font-family: var(--font-family);
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.read-more-link {
  display: table;
  padding: var(--spacing-half) var(--spacing);
  border: 1px solid var(--color-text);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: var(--color-text);
  margin: var(--spacing) auto 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.read-more-link:hover {
  background-color: var(--color-bg-alt);
  color: var(--color-text-alt);
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Are you able to post your html and css in a way that is easier to read, possibly inside a fiddle?

Comment: yes I did edit the post. Take a look please.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume you are using ahref tags for your header links so adjusting the css selector below could give you your desired outcome

```
#site-header a{
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

Comment: @jackLappa If this gave you your desired outcome please make sure you accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take each element in your header. usually its `<li>` items inside unordered list. however cannot tell for sure on your implementation because all you've put is bunch of css.
Anyway, take wrapper class for each object in menu,

Ex: Wrapper element for My projects,  Wrapper element for About me,

Then add

```
border:2px solid #eee;
padding: 10px;
```

of course you can change these values for your requirement.